# Show that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\tan^{n+2}x + \tan^nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that the integral of $$\tan^{n+2}x + \tan^nx = \frac{1}{n+1} dx$$
between the limits $\frac{\pi}{4} , 0$

I attempted to use u-substitution:
$$u = \tan x$$
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \sec^2x$$
$$\frac{du}{\sec^2x} = dx$$

Well, here's what I got (I can't input the integral sign, sorry):

$$\frac{1}{\sec^2x}(u^{n+2} + u^2) \, du$$

I don't understand how to get rid of the $\frac{1}{\sec^2x}$. I am a bit new to integration, so can someone shed some light on what the next steps would be? How do I get rid of $\sec^2x$?

Answer (score 10):

Note

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}(\tan^{n+2}x + \tan^nx )\,dx 
&= \int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^n x (\tan^2 x + 1)\,dx \\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^n x \sec^2 x \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^n x \>d(\tan x)\\
&=\frac1{n+1} \tan^{n+1}x\Big|_0^{\pi/4}=\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: It should be $\tan^{n+1}(x)$ on the last line.

Comment: @Äres thanks for catching it

Answer (score 2):

For the integral with the limits sign type `\int_{a}^{b}`, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Use the identity $\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)$, which comes from $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ after dividing through by $\cos^2(x).$

So we have $$\int_0^1\frac{u^{n+2}+u^{\color{red}{n}}}{\tan^2(x)+1} \, du$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{u^n(u^2+1)}{u^2+1} \, du=\int_0^1 u^n \, du = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use the identity
$$1+\tan^2\theta\equiv\sec^2\theta$$